How To Fix Unbound Variable?
I was running a script and got the error: ./run.sh: line 21: $1: unbound variable
Here it is
# Make sure we have something to run
**if [ "$1" = "" ]; then
**    log "Usage: $0 program [args]"
    exit 1
fi

Any help would be greatly appreciated!
I didn't write the code and I have no experience, so I don't even know where to start.

Assign a default value: if [ "${1:-help}" = "help" ]; then

[ "$1" = "" ] isn't exactly equivalent to [ "$#" -eq 0 ] but generally the latter is what you want to test

What's the first 20 lines in your code?

Remove set -u (short syntax) or set -o nounset (long syntax) from your not shown code.
From help set:

-u:  Treat unset variables as an error when substituting.


If you didn't write the script and have no intentions of fixing it, assume it's not handling the errors in a great way and, in this case, just provide the argument expected (which perhaps you know)
./run.sh whatever


What shell are you using?
Have you got a set -u somewhere in play?
Try this:
if [ "${1:-}" = "" ]; then
    log "Usage: $0 program [args]"
    exit 1
fi

OR:
if [ $# -eq 0 ]; then
    log "Usage: $0 program [args]"
    exit 1
fi

